# Experimenting with creating an opal-like material (UPDATE)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I've been wanting to create a material that attempts to mimic the look of a white opal gemstone. The biggest issue I am having is figuring out how to effectively create the streaky rainbow effect on the surface. I want the streaks to have a color-shifting look that reacts to light similar to holographic materials, and it needs to be isolated out by a noise texture mask. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Some examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I hunted around online and I found this post: https://blenderartists.org/t/opal-material/1156421/13

There is a user named JettG_G in the comments that posted a .blend file for a procedural material that pulls of the look of a polished opal incredibly well. I'm including the link to the post in case anyone is interested in the material.

Comment: Hi :). Could you please add some images of what you have in mind?

Comment: These are a few examples I've found that I think demonstrate the effect very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVHWtXzqZoE&ab_channel=S%C3%A9bastiaanStevens

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/SOs2EJ3OszE

Comment: @RobinSebbag Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.